# How to create a full width scrollable div inside a table cell?

Tags: html, css

How to turn this:

[image]

Into this:

[image]

In this fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/d3ckh9qd/2/

```css
table{
  width:100%;
  border-collapse:collapse;
}
td{
  border:1px solid red;
  padding:10px;
}
.td-left{
  width:100%;
}
.div-parent{
  width:800px;
  border:5px solid rgba(0,255,255,0.7);
}
.div-right{
  white-space:nowrap;
  background:rgba(0,0,255,0.1);
}
.pre-scrollable{
  background:rgba(0,255,0,0.3);
  padding:10px;
  white-space:pre;
  overflow:auto;
  width:100%;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="div-parent">
  The table below should not exceed parent container:
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class="td-left">
        <strong>This column should fill the remaining width, respecting the dynamic width of the right column</strong><br>
        <pre class="pre-scrollable">This should match width of the parent container and it's content should scroll horizontally.</pre>
      </td>
      <td class="td-right">
        <strong>This column should autosize to it's contents</strong><br><br>
        <div class="div-right">
          Dynamically generated content goes here
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="div-right">
          This content has different width each time it loads
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: This could be done easier and better without a table. Have you tried or would you be open to a different layout without using tables?

Comment: @Buffalo I'm open to suggestions without tables. Though, I doubt that it would be easier because we intentionally use tables for their column and row autosize behavior and their fill-the-remaining-space behavior. I'm also starting to think that this cannot be done with current CSS3 standard. I could easily achieve this in a desktop application, but CSS refuses to work without a fixed width set.

Comment: For those who wonder, sadly enough I found no other solution than to set the width if the green container to a fixed calculated value using JavaScript on domready event. In my case, the parent (cyan) container is not resizable, so once is enough. If in your case it resizable, you can use onresize event.

Comment: @Slava, did you manage to fix this issue throughout the years?

Answer (score 0):

set a fixed width by  px for the right one and a 100% width for the left one and a overflow-x

Comment: This cannot be done because the width is unknown. The width of the parent container (left column) is dynamic, and depends on the width of the right column, which has also dynamic width depending on it's content. If I set fixed width on the green div, it will either push the contents to the right (first screenshot) or will be too short. So I can't do that.

Comment: Again. Fixed width cannot be set to any element. All elements should autosize to their inner content, except the green. That one should fill the parent and scroll it's content.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to set your table-layout to fixed and then just have your td's set to the percentage you want ( in my case its 60/40 ).

https://jsfiddle.net/d3ckh9qd/6/

CSS

```
table{
  width:100%;
  border-collapse:collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
td{
  border:1px solid red;
  padding:10px;
}
.td-left{
  width:60%;
}
.td-right{
  width:40%;
}
.div-parent{
  width:100%;
  border:5px solid rgba(0,255,255,0.7);
}
.pre-scrollable{
  background:rgba(0,255,0,0.3);
  padding:10px;
  white-space:pre;
  overflow:auto;
  width:100%;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.div-right {
  word-wrap: break-word;

}
```

Comment: This isn't a solution. You can't set width to the columns. This would happen no matter how you balance the percentages: https://jsfiddle.net/d3ckh9qd/4/
That's why I wrote in the content: "This column should autosize to it's contents"

Comment: You have .div-right{
  white-space:nowrap;
  background:rgba(0,0,255,0.1);
} in your solution. Take it out as you don't need it. https://jsfiddle.net/d3ckh9qd/3/

Comment: True. But it's added for the ease of debugging, so I'll keep it. Background makes the element's edges visible, and the nowrap helps readability of the content that has instructions in it.

Comment: Well, if you want it for debugging, more power to you. But just take it out when you're ready to go live as the answer I gave is what you're looking for. If you want the right div to be scrollable like the left, just add in your .div-right { width: 100%; overflow: auto; }

Comment: Try your own example yourself: https://jsfiddle.net/d3ckh9qd/5/
(only content is changed)

Comment: The divs on the right may not be scrollable. These would be input components and dropdowns. Would be crazy to see half of an input and have to scroll to see the rest of it.

Comment: this only breaks if you have an extremely long word. If that is the case add .div-right { word-wrap: break-word; } https://jsfiddle.net/d3ckh9qd/6/

Comment: Cannot break word here because there would be INPUT controls. These cannot be broken and may contain combination of words. For example a `<select>` element with "Long text may probably pop up here". Which would appear in different languages, resulting in unpredictable length. I appreciate your intent, but please do not try to change the question so that your answer could fit. You simply do not have enough background information. If the width could be set, I wouldn't bother asking this question on stackoverflow.